Scaling symmetry of Klein-Gordon Equation
Why does the scaling transformation \begin{align}
x^\mu &\rightarrow \lambda x^\mu \\
\end{align}
of a scalar field under the Klein-Gordon equation, \begin{equation}
\Box \phi(x) = 0
\end{equation}
typically take the form,
$$\begin{align*}
\phi(x) &\rightarrow \lambda^{-\Delta} \phi(\lambda x)= \phi'(x')
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$
(Am I correct to call the transformed field $\phi'(x')$? or should it be $\phi'(x)$?)
and not like,
$$\begin{align*}
\phi(x) &\rightarrow \phi'(x') = \lambda^{-\Delta} \phi(x)~?
\end{align*}\tag{2}$$
As per my understanding, for a given transformation to be a symmetry the following condition must be satisfied
\begin{align*}
S[\phi'(x')] = S[\phi(x)]
\end{align*}
This leads to the second condition rather than the first.

The two line only differ in the sign of $\Delta$.  Isn't it just an issue of $\Delta$'s definition?

@T.P.Ho I am confused with the different notations followed in different QFT texts. This might be a different question, but in some texts, when discussing Noether's Theorem, The total variation of the Lagrangian, $\Delta L$ is considered  while some texts describe it by the functional change $\delta L$. What is the connection between the two derivations?

I see the confusion now.  It is some very unfortunate notation, and used to bother the hell out of me, too.
That scaling transformation $x \rightarrow \lambda x$ is to be understood in the active sense: suppose you originally sit at $x=1$, you literally stand up and move to $x = \lambda$.  But then you (or the book) fail to mention the second part: you rescale the distance so that you are again at $x' = 1$ in the new unit.
Let's say you draw a line across surface of the earth and measure the elevation along the way.  The data can be represented as a function $\phi(x)$, where elevation $\phi$ and distance from starting point $x$ are both measured in meter.  Now consider a rescaling into km, and your eq (1) gives the very sensible relation:
$$
\phi'(k) = (1000)^{-1} \, \phi(1000\,k).
$$
where k is the numerical value of $x$ and $x'$.  The function has $\Delta = -1$ since $\Delta$ usually counts $(\text{length})^{-1}$.

Thanks! Also can you suggest some resource to read about Noether's theorem, addressing the difference between the functional change ($\delta L$ )and total change ($\Delta L$)? In Fradkin they have used the functional change of lagrangian density, while I have also found other resources where they have started defining the change in the action using the total change.....

@HypnoticZebra I think SE policy is that you should ask the separate question in a separate post, and it would be helpful if you provide a little more background because I'm not too sure what difference you perceive here.  Either way, the variation vanishes, right?
